# Unable to connect Sip softphone to Freeswitch

Tags: freeswitch, softphone

I just started freeswitch 1.4.5 on ubuntu 14.04 x64 and tried to connect SIP phone to freeswitch, but it is not registering. I am using default configuration.

I am using 1001 as username. 1234 as password and 192.168.1.5 as domain on sip phone.
Machine on which freeswitch is installed has local ip 192.168.1.5.

I also have asterisk on same machine and I am able to connect softphone to asterisk.

Comment: Asterisk and FreeSWITCH, both being SIP servers, bind to the same ports. They cannot run simultaneously without reconfiguration. When you say you have Asterisk on the same machine, do you mean you're trying to run them both at the same time?

Comment: I resolved the issue. The problem was that Asterisk ran automatically on system startup

Comment: @user3841111 Did you change any settings in the files where freeswitch is installed? I am experiencing the same problem with Zoipher and Xlite.